# c++ function with static variable returning next value in array

Tags: c, function, pointers, static

Create a function with a static variable that is a pointer (with a default argument of zero). When the caller provides a value for this argument it is used to point at the beginning of an array of int. If you call the function with a zero argument (using the default argument), the function returns the next value in the array, until it sees a “-1” value in the array (to act as an end-of-array (indicator). Exercise this function in main( ).

Here is what I have :

```
int pr(int *p = 0) {
    static int* po =0 ;
    if (p) {
        po = p;
        return *po;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }

    if (*p == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    return *po++;    
}

int ar[] = {2,5,1,2,6,-1};

int main() {

    pr(ar);

    int pl;
    pl = pr();
    while (pl != -1) {
        cout << pl << endl;
        pl = pr();
    }
}
```

When I start it, nothing gets printed and I dont know why. Any help ?

Comment: What is the function argument used for if it isn't zero?

Comment: @KerrekSB to initialize the static variable

Comment: OK. And what does the function return, for all cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to keep the next array index around, too:

```
int f(int* a = NULL) {
  static int* arr = NULL;    // internal state ...
  static int idx = 0;        // ...in these two vars

  // Reset the internal state if a new array is given
  if (a != NULL) {
    arr = a;
    idx = 0;
  }

  // #1
  if (arr == NULL || arr[idx] == -1) { return -1; }

  return arr[idx++];
}
```

I made some assumptions about the parts you didn't specify in your question on the line marked `#1`. If no pointer has yet been provided, or if the array end has previously been reached, we just return `-1` each time.